# How to get the details of specific tag in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is the code and I need to get the "DDetail" details.

```
<div style="float:left;padding-left: 7%">
   <h2 class="lotnumber style19Bold222" style="float:left"> LOT DETAILS </h2>
   <br>
   <p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
      <b class="boldDetails">Materials:</b>
   </p>
   <p class="style14Reg555"> MDetail </p>
   <p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
      <b class="boldDetails">Measurements:</b>
   </p>
   <p class="style14Reg555"> MeDetail </p>
   <p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
      <b class="boldDetails">Size Notes:</b>
   </p>
   <p class="style14Reg555"> total height </p>
   <p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
      <b class="boldDetails">Description:</b>
   </p>
   <p class="style14Reg555"> stepped square reverse </p>
   <p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
      <b class="boldDetails">Markings:</b>
   </p>
   <p class="style14Reg555"> MarDetail </p>
   <p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
      <b class="boldDetails">Condition:</b>
   </p>
   <p class="style14Reg555"> CDetail </p>
</div>
```

I tried using XPath but it's not working properly because `<p>` is not consistent.
I am using JAVA to get this details.

Comment: what you mean *get the "DDetail" details*?

Comment: @pArAs I tried using xpath but <p> value is not same all the time.So I didnt get proper answer.

Comment: @Andersson I want this tag details. <p class="style14Reg555"> DDetail </p>

Comment: Tag is `<p>` (paragraph). It could not have any "details". So сlarify: do you want to get text ('DDetail') of mentioned element or it's attributes(`class`) or something different?

Comment: @Andersson Basically I want the description details and DDetail is the description of it. So I want DDetail.

Comment: @Hiten, So you just want to get text `" DDetail"` of `<p>` element? What programming language you use?

Comment: @Andersson I am using JAVA.
<p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;">
<b class="boldDetails">Description:</b>
</p>
<p class="style14Reg555">stepped square reverse</p>

Basically I want "stepped square reverse" detail.

Comment: @Hiten try with provided answer and let me know...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `DDetail` on the the basis of `Description` try below `xPath` :-

- Using `following` axis :

  ```
  (//*[contains(text(), 'Description')]/following::p)[1]
  ```
- Using `preceding` axis :

  ```
  (//p[preceding::b[contains(text(), 'Description')]])[1]
  ```

**Note** :- If you want other details Just change the bold text like if you want `MDetail` just change on one of the aboive `xpath` text `Description` to `Materials`

Or If you want only on the basis of class name `style14Reg555`, try using index in `xpath` as below :-

```
(//p[@class = 'style14Reg555'])[4]
```

Comment: I tried with this solution and I got the details of description.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the tag `<p class="style14Reg555"> DDetail </p>` you can use the XPath `//p[text()=' DDetail ']`.

You didn't specify a language, so here's some Java below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()=' DDetail ']"));
```

Comment: If OP wants to get `DDetail` text how can you suppose xpath should be that text, is it make sense..??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I don't know what OP wants but what he said he wants is "to get the "DDetail" details.". He said it twice. What I have provided is the way to get the tag that contains DDetail as OP requested. You should read his question and comments more carefully before downvoting.

Comment: Basically I want the description details and DDetail is the description of it. So I want DDetail. 

For Example::
<p class="details style14SemiBold222 styleCapitalize" style="line-height:22px;"> 
<b class="boldDetails">Description:</b> </p> 
<p class="style14Reg555">stepped square reverse</p> 


Basically I want "stepped square reverse" string.

Comment: @Hiten In your last comment you put details and HTML that are not in your question. Please update your question with a specific, detailed example of what you are looking for. I'm still confused on what you want.

Comment: @JeffC I just changed the details of description.
I changed "DDetail" into "stepped square reverse" text.

Comment: @Hiten where did you change it? I don't see any edits to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to get the "DDetail" details , java:

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/p[8]"))
```

Comment: I tried this bt it didnt work because <p> value is not consistence.
Sometime DDetail be in p[7] or else.
So this is not working.